# Python menu from list in Tkinter

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, tkinter

Here I have a list which I am getting from the cursor of MYSQL connector. I have no problem in fetching the data. But I am interested in making a menu using the `OptionMenu` feature of tkinter with the data I received. Here, is what I am trying

```
from tkinter import *

r = Tk()
name_  = StringVar()

name = [('John',),('Jimmy',),('Smith',),('Rosel',)]  
#Here I am directly giving the list, but this the output which I  get from cursor of MYSQL

l=[]
for i in range(len(name)-1):
   l.append(name[i][0])

print(l)

t = tuple(l)

name_.set('Select Student')

option = OptionMenu(r,name_,l)
option.pack()
```

But I don't think this helps as what I get is the whole list printed as a single option.
Please help me.....

Comment: Instantiate your OptionMenu like so `option = OptionMenu(r, name_, *l)` to treat your list as multiple arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use python's `*` operator to expand the list when calling `OptionMenu` (eg: `*l`):

```
option = OptionMenu(r, name_, *l)
```

Answer (score -1):

I hope it helps:

```
     from tkinter import *
     from tkinter import ttk
     root = Tk()
     root.title("mysql")
     root.geometry(("400x400"))
     class Mysql:
         def __init__(self,parent):
             self.parent = parent
             self.options = [('John',),('Jimmy',),('Smith',),('Dave',)]
             self.var = StringVar(self.parent)
             self.var.set("Select Student")
             self.option = ttk.OptionMenu(self.parent,self.var,*self.options)
             self.option.pack()
     Mysql(root)
     root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Why have you posted 2 answers? That said code only answers are not very useful. Please add a description of what you have done to fix the problem and why.

Comment: Yes, this can also be done, but using a long defination obviously slows my program and I just want one menu, and I am a student and what I am trying is to make a student database management system as a part of my project work. So, using only ```name_ ,*1``` is ok. Thanks.....

Answer (score -2):

Please let me know if this is not what you want:

## python 3

```
    from tkinter import *
    from tkinter import ttk
    root = Tk()
    root.title("mysql")
    root.geometry("400x400")
    var = StringVar(root)
    var.set("select student")
    option = ttk.OptionMenu(root,var,'','John','Jimmy','Smith','Rosel')
    option["width"] = 20
    option.pack()
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: This won't work because they don't want to hard-code the menu, they want to populate it with data from a database.